# Can a Force-user's natural ability develop over time? Is it better for a Jedi or Sith to begin training later?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, sith

Although most examples here come from or are *potentially* from the Skywalker line (which may or may not make their offspring more powerful),I want to ask, **why is it that the Jedi order** (before the events of a New Hope when force-sensitives became a rarity and they trained literally anyone 'cos, you know... no choice) **thinks it's better to train Jedi at a young age?**

Yoda complained about training Luke at the age of 19 in TESB, and even declared an eight-year-old Anakin to be too old. However, both turned out to be extrememly powerful Jedi, and even an untrained Leia was proficient at sensing events through the force.

Although I hate to bring this up with no clear answers yet, but maybe it'll be pertinent in the future:
Rey, who received the least amount of training, was instantly able to master Jedi mind-tricks (which stumped a similarly-aged Ezra on his first- and conscious- attempt at doing so), great lightsaber fighting skills and Force abilities.

Is it simply because these Jedi were of the Skywalker line that makes them more powerful -passing on those (*whispers* midichlorians) like a pro...?

---

Why not allow users to develop both mentally and physically before teaching them about the Force? After all, Anakin- the youngest of these examples and longest trained- was not a liability due to his age, but due to his mental instability.

Comment: Bad luck, Mikasa. Sorry. :(

Comment: @Jonah muahhaha I still get points though, it's all good ;) Maybe I should learn to read questions now that mine are becoming less imaginative...